# How to identify what って means in different situations

Tags: meaning, usage, definitions

って can be used at least 3 different ways that I know of.

1. Standard って form that most people learn first.て,って,んで,いて,いで etc.
2. って for quoting people.
3. って for making a demand/command statement.
4. A tutorial I'm watching says って=という as well.

Are there any other usages of って I should know?

Most importantly, how do I know which form of って is being used? Is there an easy way to know which one is being used?

Comment: Context. Context.

Comment: Take a look at [って entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) in Jisho. It is comprehensive enough. IMO definitions 1, 4, 5, 9 are worth memorizing.

Comment: What is the _"Standard って form that most people learn first"_?  Do you mean the verb ending, as in 切る→切[っ]{●}[て]{●}?

Comment: @Grumpy Bread - If you're casually asking "how do I know", the comments already answer your question perfectly. But if you're asking "how does one read between the context" or "what is the thought process behind reading the lines", then you'll remain grumpy as the comments aren't really helpful. In order to make you a happy bread, you might want to clarify to what extent you seek in terms of "how"?

Comment: I clarified my #1 point @EiríkrÚtlendi . You are correct. 
Also, it seems maybe I'm not asking this question properly. Probably because I just don't understand a lot of what is going on. The idea of context makes sense but I was wondering if there was something more definitive that would make it easier for more to know what is being said when I see a って being used.

Comment: #3 is the plain-style equivalent of one of the usages of #1. They are clearly different in form from #2 and #4 as they are part of inflected verb forms while #2 and #4 are not.

Comment: @GrumpyBread Context is the key. I think you're question will be best asked by finding some example sentences where the meaning of って is unclear to you. That way people can provide more specific help.